# What to use when creating a stand alone app from a web app?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, platform

I was asked to create a stand alone application from a web app  - I have to keep the same look and feel and of course the functionality. Basically, the end result should be the following: a standalone product that looks and does exactly the same thing as its web - based counterpart. 
I have been developing for some time with asp.net and c#, but I doubt this is easy to convert to a standalone C# application. 
I heard some stuff about xaml - but I am not sure what to use to make my life a little bit easier. 
Should I just leave the .Net platform and turn to Java? Or if I keep the .Net what should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "stand alone app"? A WinForms application that can be installed on a workstation and perform its logic without any connection to the outside world, or a WinForms application that is a client which will interact (presumably through WCF Services) with a server?

Answer (score 0):

better to keep in .net as it would be easier to migrate the code.
and .net is better than java in terms of desktop apps.

Comment: ...especially when you have to port your application to Linux at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Web and desktop apps are fundamentally quite different (as much as ASP.NET Web Forms developers would argue to the contrary), but you should be able to reuse a lot of your business logic (especially if you separated your concerns properly). I'd suggest starting with a new Windows Forms project, building out an equivalent set of controls (buttons, grids, etc), and then looking for opportunities to borrow UI logic (click events, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If your web app is written in ASP.NET, then I would stick with that.

If your web app was built properly and the new app has to have the exact same functionality, then you should be able to re-use most of the code whether you use WPF or Windows forms. You would just need to rebuild the UI.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the WPF quite slow?Visual Studio 2010 is using that and it takes quite some time to load....

Comment: @ionaik, I don't think WPF is that much slower, if at all. VS2010 for me is actually way faster than VS2008. Whether you choose WPF or Winforms is really up to you, whatever you think would be better for your project. As everyone has pointed out, either is a good choice because it allows you to re-use your .NET code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with WPF... I only observed that on vista it is slow (corrrection: my vista ;D) I did not try it in any other OS...<br /> My boss told me today to look for some nice gui classes in C# - like the swing for java (he is using java mostly) - do you know what I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the .Net code and see how much you can reuse. Tell that you can't make the user interface look and work exactly the same and that there will be a lot of minor and some major differences. Add that the look and feel will be the same with added functionality.

See if you can reuse the basic data loading code. Then simply create a form/panel/tabpage for each page in the web application and see what you can reuse.

Or easier yet, create a simple windows application using a browser window and simply point to the existing app.

Comment: Isn't that what Silverlight tends to do? I've been reading on some other forums and a guy said that he rewrote the code in Silverlight and now he can use it as both stand-alone and web app... I thought that Silverlight was designed to be a part of a webpage...